# Execution Order of pymssql's cursor.executemany()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymssql

Does `cursor.executemany(...)` of the `pymssql` module have a guaranteed execution order?

```
import pymssql

# Example retrieved from: http://pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html

# ...
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")
cursor = conn.cursor()

# ...
cursor.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO persons VALUES (%d, %s, %s)",
    [(1, 'John Smith', 'John Doe'),
     (2, 'Jane Doe', 'Joe Dog'),
     (3, 'Mike T.', 'Sarah H.')])
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

See also: http://pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html

In a real scenario, I require to update values in a specific order (I have an ordered array of tuples) and would like to avoid execute those updates one by one with `cursor.execute(...)`.

---

Looks like PEP 249 is very open with its requirement...

> Prepare a database operation (query or command) and then execute it against all parameter sequences or mappings found in the sequence seq_of_parameters.
>
> Modules are free to implement this method using multiple calls to the .execute() method or by using array operations to have the database process the sequence as a whole in one call.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany

That raises another question... Does `pymssql`'s implementation of PEP 249 execute them anyway one by one with `cursor.execute(...)`?

Comment: Please see this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html It shows that all your rows will be merged in SQL level.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like the module `mysql.connector` does honor the order of the tuple but unfortunately I can't draw a conclusion that `pymssql` does the same if I read PEP 249...

Comment: How about the source code? I think based on the source code, `pymssql` doesn't implement this optimization but just execute them one by one : ( ref: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/blob/891b20e29e4e247c17b202e8e34e5c739b6090ef/src/pymssql.pyx#L472

Comment: Yep, I was just digging in there too... :) Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: Actually not, it is too short to be an answer. But, to help others I will :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> def executemany(self, operation, params_seq):
>     self.description = None
>     rownumber = 0
>     for params in params_seq:
>         self.execute(operation, params)
>         # support correct rowcount across multiple executes
>         rownumber += self._rownumber
>     self._rownumber = rownumber
> ```

According to the source code, the `executemany` function just iterate the given sequence and call `execute`.

ref: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/blob/891b20e29e4e247c17b202e8e34e5c739b6090ef/src/pymssql.pyx#L472